# Regexp query seems to be ignored in elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {
          "query_string" : {
            "query" : "dog cat",
            "analyzer" : "standard",
            "default_operator" : "AND",
            "fields" : ["title", "content"]
          }
        },
        {
          "range" : {
            "dateCreate" : {
              "gte" : "2018-07-01T00:00:00+0200",
              "lte" : "2018-07-31T23:59:59+0200"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp" : {
            "articleIds" : {
              "value" : ".*?(2561|30|540).*?",
              "boost" : 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The fields title, content and articleIds are of type text, dateCreate is of type date. The articleIds field contains some IDs (comma-separated).

Ok, what happens now? I execute the query an get two results: Both documents contain the words "dog" and "cat" in the title or in the content. So far it's correct.
But the second result has the number 3507 in the articleIds field which doesn't match to my query. It seems that the regexp is ignored because title and content already match. What is wrong here?

And here's the document that should not match my query but does:

```
{
  "_index" : "example",
  "_type" : "doc",
  "_id" : "3007780",
  "_score" : 21.223656,
  "_source" : {
    "dateCreate" : "2018-07-13T16:54:00+0200",
    "title" : "",
    "content" : "Its raining cats and dogs.",
    "articleIds" : "3507"
  }
}
```

And what I'm expecting is that this document should not be in the results because it contains 3507 which is not part of my query...

Comment: Can you show a document that is in the result but shouldn't?

Comment: Most likely, one of the other id's matches. Do you expect `2561,3507` to **not** match?

Comment: I updated my post!

Comment: Strange I just did that in my local and it's working fine.

Comment: Can you post your index mappings?